# How to make dropdown menu's DOM available in the page before first click in ngx-bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

In ngx-bootstrap when we create a dropdown, there is no HTML(DOM) present for Dropdown-menu class(when you inspect the code), I want to add animation to it but not able to since there is no DOM, to begin with.

How can I show the DOM before the first click of the dropdown?
Please go to this link 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

[When dropdown is not clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8jaK.jpg)

[When Dropdown is clicked for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J6W2.jpg)

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Comment: Hi @AJarofClay i have updated the question please have a look